# UNIQUE constraint failed: account_customuser.username

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with user's signup. I use Django.

When I register the first user everything is fine and the user appears in the admin panel. The problem occurs when I want to register the second user. After submiting the signup form, this error shows up:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: account_customuser.username
```

So it looks like the user will not be saved because the username (email) is not unique, but the email of the second user is different from the first one. Only superuser and first registered user appear at the admin panel.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from orders.models import Order


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255, default='')
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    orders = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CreateUserForm


def signup(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'views/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

`forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['zip_code', 'address', 'street', 'first_name',
                  'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you still have a `username` column in your database, but you're not creating users with usernames. So the constraint is probably failing because you'll have two users with a `username` of `None`.

If you don't need the `username` column, you need to add `username = None` to your `CustomUser` class and generate the migrations to remove the column.